# Graphql file path autocompletion in VSCODE

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, graphql

Looks like my vscode refuse to give me auto-completion on .graphql file import path… Do you have any idea why ?[image: error]

I've specific Gql extension activated…

```
Name: GraphQL for VSCode
Id: kumar-harsh.graphql-for-vscode
Description: GraphQL syntax highlighting, linting, auto-complete, and more!
Version: 1.15.3
Publisher: Kumar Harsh
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kumar-harsh.graphql-for-vscode
```

Also definition TS

```
declare module '*/get-course.gql' {
  import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';
  const defaultDocument: DocumentNode;
  export const GetCourses: DocumentNode;

  export default defaultDocument;
}
```

It doesn't give auto-complete in js file neither…

Thank in advance…

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an almost 2 years old question but I just encountered the same problem.

I just wanted to post the answer for anyone with the same problem.

Installing this very popular [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) (*~5M downloads*) plugin solved my problem and VSCode started showing autocompletion for my graphql files.

**Before installing the plugin**:
[image]

**After installing the plugin**:
[image]

Comment: You're an exceptional human being, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately looks like this extension  doesn't support paths, like aliases "@/something" at the moment.

Comment: @JoãoHamerski No idea... It has been a very long time since I worked on GraphQL APIs. If you find a better extension, try to update it or post a new answer 

Answer (score -1):

Looks .graphql filetypes are not included in default vs code autocomplete plugin.

You can install GraphQL prisma.vscode-graphql or similar plugin to achieve this.

Comment: I doesn't work neither… And i can't find a clear way to integrate this tool from a frontend… :(